# What is the space of $\{ f \mid \int_0^1 \left(f''(x)\right)^2 \,dx <\infty \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, notation

What is the space of $\left\{ f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R} \mid \int_0^1 \left(f''(x)\right)^2 \,dx <\infty \right\}$? Our professor denote this space as $C^2 \left([0,1]\right)$ but this does not agree with the usual definition of $C^2\left([0,1]\right)$ that I see. I am wondering if there is any standard notation for this space?

Comment: I suspect your professor is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particular case of the so called Sobolev spaces. You should check its more general definition.